# Lost Facebook share count when i switched my site from http: to https

Tags: facebook, count, share

When I switched my site from http: to https: the Facebook share count reduced to 4 which was more than 100 earlier. Is there any way to restore the lost share counts. I made no changes to permalink structure or any other settings in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook treats HTTP and HTTPS URLs as two different objects, even if the rest is identical.

What you need to do to keep likes and comments, when you move from HTTP to HTTPS, is explicitly mentioned in the social plugins FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#moving-urls